# How can I web scrape google cache in large volumes?

Tags: web-scraping, proxy, google-cloud-platform, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to download a few million web pages that google has already indexed. I've used proxies with mixed success directly but for the bandwidth I'm considering it's relatively cost prohibitive.

Is there any way to get access to google's cache of websites with datacenter ip's? - I've not gotten it to work reliably.

I've tried using HTTRACK, outwit and writing a basic script on google cloud.

I always run into limitations with proxy services.

In a perfect world I could just batch download google cache pages.

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking for?  Do you just want an arbitrary set of a few million web pages worth of data or do you want web data from some specific domain set?  How much bandwidth do you have to receive the data?  How big do you anticipate the data to be?  Is it a one-time download or ongoing?

Comment: I've been working on a few different specific websites, all based in real estate although I don't see how that's directly involved. The direction I'm looking into uses the caches bing stores of these websites. If I use proxies to access it directly then it's a bandwidth problem but if not than it's a non issue. It will only be ongoing is the project proves decently successful.

Comment: what are you using of the google-cloud-platform? why that tag is added here?